# Always printing "Please fill out all fields" even if all fields are full?

Tags: php

In my code, it should print "Please fill out all fields" if you do not have them filled out, but it never proceeds with signup as it should, and always prints the error message; though I did a test where it prints all the variables to make sure that they have a value, and they do, so I don't see the problem

```
if($_POST['signUp']){
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
  } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  }

  $display = $_POST['newDisplay'];
  $username = $_POST['newUsername'];
  $pass = $_POST['newPassword'];
  $email = $_POST['newEmail'];

  if ($display && $password && $username && $email) {
    $signedUp = SignUp($username,$pass,$display,$ip,$email);
    echo $signUpCode[$signedUp];
  }
  else {
    echo "<p class='BasicText'>Please fill out all fields.</p>"; 
  }
}
```

I know that all the HTML fields are working, because if I remove the if/else it works fine signing you up.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and post the results here (your validation is poor at best as it is. You really could improve it tremendously).

Comment: Do you actually code like that (with no indentation) or is it just some sort of a problem with your copying and pasting? I would go nuts trying to debug my own code.

Comment: Problem with formatting; sorry, I have trouble formatting on here always when I copy my code

Comment: @Sam Paste in your code with all its indentation intact, then highlight & click the `{}` editor toolbar button to make a code block or `ctl-k`.

Comment: You use $password instead of $pass.

Comment: This might be personal preference, but I tend not to do `if ($var)` when $var is a string. Instead, convert it to a boolean depending on what I'm trying to do. If you want to make sure it's set, do `if (isset($var))` or if I want to make sure it's set and not empty `if (!empty($var))`, etc. This way you avoid type conversion issues. Maybe you want to make sure it's a non-empty string, but if the string is `"0"` then doing `if ($var)` will be false.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is in the condition you refer to `$password`, but the variable is `$pass`

```
if ($display && $pass && $username && $email) {
```

Comment: @Sam: **Rule #1 of debugging:** always have [error reporting enabled](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/220538).

Comment: Rule #2 of PHP debugging: Don't just enable `error_reporting`, also display errors on screen. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at runtime, or set both in `php.ini`.